# Tomcat cluster in 2 different machine 2 pvt IP on same subnet

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing

I have two tomcat instances running in Clustered Environment into 2 servers.

Assume we have test.jsp is there in both Instances.

I want hit one single real IP which will be take service from tomcat1 or tomcat 2.

How can we do that?

Comment: any one please help me on this issue. I have already setup the cluster but session is not replicating......also for the above issue how can u done in realtime scenario like i want to hit cluster.test.me then it will be server by node1/node2...how can i set the IP setting...

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set up a cluster successfully, I wonder why you did not take the next step: Placing a load balancer before it which forwards requests to the Tomcat instances. This can quite easily be done with setting up an Apache instance using either [mod_jk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192636) or - the modern way - [mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html). Apache can then use that *one single real IP* address to expose the cluster's services.